# Spring Boot and Couchbase Connection Error

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am starting to learn spring boot and couchbase together, and implementing a simple custom query. However when I hit localhost:8889/agents/findByAgentId/14045, I got "this site can't be reached" error. What I missed here? I will appreciate any response. Thank you

here is the Entity Class

```
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Field;

@Document
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Agent {

@Id
@NotNull
@Field
private String AgentLeaderId;

@Field
private String agentPreference;

@Field
private String agency;

@Field
private String mobilePhone;

}
```

Here is the Configuration Class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.config.AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class AgentConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

@Override
public String getConnectionString() {
    return ("127.0.0.1");
}

@Override
public String getUserName() {
    return "******";
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return "*******";
}

@Override
public String getBucketName() {
    return "******";
}
}
```

Here is the Repository

```
import com.bit.pruleads.entity.Agent;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.N1qlPrimaryIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.ViewIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "primaryLeadsData")
public interface AgentRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Agent, String > {

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE agentLeaderId = $1 AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    List<Agent> findByAgentId(String agentId);

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE mobilePhone = $1 AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    List<Agent> findAgentsByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);

}
```

Controller Class

```
import com.bit.pruleads.entity.Agent;
import com.bit.pruleads.repository.AgentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class AgentController {

@Autowired
private AgentRepository agentRepository;

public AgentController(AgentRepository agentRepository) {
    this.agentRepository = agentRepository;
}

@PostMapping("/findByAgentId/{id}")
public List<Agent> findByAgentId(@PathVariable String id) {
    return agentRepository.findByAgentId(id);
}

@PostMapping("/findAgentsByPhoneNumber/{phoneNumber}")
public List<Agent> findAgentByPhoneNumber(@PathVariable String phoneNumber) {
    return agentRepository.findAgentsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
}

}
```

Here is the pom file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the Application properties

```
#Server port
server.port =8889
```

Here is some of the Logs

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Bootstrapping Spring Data Couchbase repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 456ms. 
Found 0 Couchbase 
repository interfaces.
Bootstrapping Spring Data Couchbase repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35ms. 
Found 1 Couchbase repository interfaces.
Opened bucket "leads-data" 
Started PruleadsApplication in 7.502 seconds (JVM running for 8.685)
Closed bucket "leads-data" 
Node disconnected 
Completed shutdown and closed all open buckets 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have  `spring-boot-starter-web` included in your pom. With no web server, spring-boot starts and finds it has nothing to do so it will just stop.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't know that I have to include this dependency, now my app is up and running, thank you again. However, I still has another issue here, it does not expose any endpoints, except all endpoints beneath /actuator

Comment: can you provide more information? Is there an error message? How are you attempting to call your interface?

Comment: I am sorry, now it is working fine. Seems like eclipse cache issue. After restart and everything works fine. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use this version instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You will need to change a few imports, so check the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Remove the annotations @N1qlPrimaryIndexed and @ViewIndexed, they have been replacing by new annotations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.indexing

You don't need to create the indexes right now, just make sure that you have a primary index on your database and you should be able to get something up and running:

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON MY_BUCKET
```

Here is an example:

```
https://github.com/deniswsrosa/spring-data-couchbase-quickstart
```

Just Run the class "QuickStartCouchbase" and after the application startup, the method "run" inside "CmdRunner" should be called.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried this solution but didn't work. I assuming the issue is related to node connection. Spring boot failed to have connection to the couchbase server, but I dont know how to fix it. The configuration class is configured based on spring data couchbase docs.

Comment: @TunggulSagala This one should work https://github.com/deniswsrosa/spring-data-couchbase-quickstart . Just run the QuickStartCouchbase class, the CmdRunner should be called after the application startup, it will run some demo methods